# The repeating command in LaTeX3 and \newcommand both use #1 and they have a clash

Tags: latex3

Just as the title says, both `\newcommand` and `\int_step_inline:nn` use `#1` and they get in conflict.

That is to say, I want to use `#1` to refer to the variable that records how many times the repetition has gone (which is the correct use of `\int_step_inline:nn`, but LaTeX thought that it was to refer to an argument of my new command.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: You probably need to use `##1` for `\int_step_inline:nn`. Can you show as minimal example?

Comment: In LaTeX `#` is quite special (parameter character). It indicates the parameter of a macro you want to define. The `\int_step_inline:nn` function internally just defines a temporary function to reinsert the code, so you'll need to pass to it `#1`, note however that inside a macro definition you'll need to use two `#` to give a single macro parameter (so `##1` like @Qrrbrbirlbel said), however if you were to use another nested `\int_step_inline:nn` you'd have to double the number of `#`, so there you'd need `####1`.